# Why are most programming languages built on top of frameworks?

Tags: architecture, frameworks, programming-languages

As programming languages continue to evolve, we see these programming languages that sit on top of frameworks such as Java or .NET, and that's good.

In your opinion, what are the best reasons to build a language on top of a framework?

Disclaimer: i'm not trying to prove something , i thought this was a good topic of discussion

Comment: Aren't frameworks build on top of languages ?

Comment: yeah but the tables have turned my friend :)

Comment: I think this statement is false. If you restrict to .NET or java world, okay, but you forget C, C++, COBOL, Fortran, Prolog, Common Lisp, OCaml, Haskell, Brainfuck and Befunge which are not based on any so called "framework".

Comment: look at implementations on frameworks my good friend , it will exceed the programming languages that are not based on frameworks

Comment: Which programming languages are built on top of frameworks? The .NET and JVM languages, but what else?

Comment: i'm just wondering why the Question Voted Down

Comment: @Alexandre Although C++ is not based on any framework (by the means of a standard), many programmers fail to take advantage of the extensibility (by means of external libraries) this language encourages. I often see that programmers reduce them selfs to a framework trained monkeys. In this way a language is often tightly  (and wrongly) identified with framework (by programmers, not by the standard).

Comment: @Marcin: I can't agree more, that's why we see such questions asked here.

Comment: but C++ is not good for everything , i love C++ , i used to work with Borland C++ 3.1 & waiting for C++0x , so there is a reason why programmers made & used frameworks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one word: Reuse.

Frameworks are large collections of classes, methods, etc., like libraries. Unlike libraries, they also enforce *rules*, so to speak, that define programming standards.

Answer (score 5):

If you ever programmed COM objects by hand (ATL is even worse), or written C programs with the Win32 API, you'll understand easily that .NET is a good thing. It is a modernization of arcane difficult techniques with a certain lack of organization.

I can't agree with you: with the notable exception of C# and Java, languages are not tied to any "framework". Frameworks are just a huge collection of libraries, along with a philosophy, like every huge library. To me, this is just a word for marketing purposes. You can call .NET the "standard windows library" for instance.

Is the POSIX API a framework ? Is the collection of Python libraries a framework ? Is the C++ standard library, or Boost, a framework ? Is Qt a framework ? Is BLAS/LAPACK a framework ? Is Intel Threading Building blocks a framework ?

The world doesn't revolve around .NET or Java.

Comment: To me, a library is something that provides an API for one primary function (e.g. a Sockets library or a DirectX library). A framework provides a range of core features that you will need to build applications. I'd argue that python-lib/STL/boost/etc are frameworks (if only small ones) as they provide a basis upon which almost any application can be built, not just an API to access a single system/feature. What sets Java and .net aside from these frameworks is simply that they encompass so much more stuff within them, and this vastly increases the utility of the associated language.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to have one universal standard that is well written and well tested than for every programmer have to reinvent the same wheel over and over. The number of string classes written around the world before the likes of MFC's CString and Java/.net String classes was simply ridiculous.

Comment: good example! I think there were about 6 or so windows strings? `LPSTR, LPCSTR, LPWCSTR,c_str(),char[]....` I just used anything with trail and mostly error!

Comment: That's not all: now we have CString, `std::string`, `std::wstring` (and `System::string` for C++/CLI). When I write legacy COM code, I still have to use those pesky `BSTR`. I really bless C# and .NET for not having to deal with these any more.

Comment: C++0x will add `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` to the mix.

Comment: Exactly! Aerospace engineers waste so much time reinventing wheels for space shuttles, instead of using the stone wheel already invented 5000 years ago

Answer (score 1):

Probably because:

> *If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulder of the
>   giants.*

Not to mention the existing prospering community, the plethora of libraries etc. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to be the first persons that doesn't agree with the "one framework to rule them all" approach. 
I believe that engineers should use the right tools (available) to solve the problem. 
Believe is a good word since each software development approach/methodology has a great number of "believers" followed back by significant amount of pessimists :)

But, going back to the question... I see 2 main drawback of a framework approach:

1) It can be an overkill
  Sometimes you just need a simple solution for a simple problem. You do not need a tool that solves/links with solutions for all problems of mankind.

2) "If you're not with use you're against us"
The fact is that it is impossible to provide a big, mature framework of Optimal/easy/adequate solutions for all problems it tries to address. So sometimes you need to introduce an external tool. This can be a pain in the ... For example invoking a Qt signals from a non-qt threads does not work out of the box (a failed to make it work at all). In this case you may find yourself "fighting" with the framework. Instead of making your life easier it can make you want to inflict severe damage upon yourself/other people :)

One of reasons for two previous points is that it's really hard not to make assumptions.
Frameworks are made often on many assumptions that a programmer will do/use A, B, C... standard/framework component. Once hard-coded assumptions are introduced the chances that the framework will be modular are falling down as a piano from the 10th floor :)

On the other side the "right tool for problem" approach allows a programmer to focus on one problem and implement it well. By saing well I mean:
1) Data agnostic
  For example (C++) if you work with strings do not a assume a string type. Allow user to work with different strings from different frameworks: QString, wxString, std::string...
2) Policy agnostic/extendable
Programmer may like the overall way the frameworks implements something, but may find that one tiny aspect renders the framework unusable for him. That's why framework user should have the ability to introduce his own policy in some key parts
An example of family sharing this approach are internal/external DSL implementations (Domain Specific Language). A concrete example(C++) is a Blitz++ library.

All I said before is also valid for the high level languages. For example there are may languages build on the Java Virtual Machine (Scalla to start with).

Hope I made some good points.
Best Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but .NET isn't built on top of a framework. In fact, it's the other way around. Frameworks often extend languages as the languages become more powerful and they often ship in the same pack with language compilers. However, there are also [Domain-Specific Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) which are built on top of an existing framework and an existing language. Technically these are not languages but more of a scripting API. C#.NET and VB.NET language specs haven't actually changed all that much with the exception of optional parameters, named arguments, co/contra variance and a few others. It's the framework around them that recently gave us expressions, linq and etc.

EDIT 1: Unless we consider virtual machines such as JVM a framework, than i can see how that could be true.

EDIT 2: Having understood the question, the answer is simple. It's portability (in terms of compiling to an intermediate language when you're dealing with Java or .NET environments) and the ability to leverage the power of the framework.

Comment: i didnt say .net is built on top of a framework , i said that some languages are built on top of frameworks , you can see ruby or python implementations as an example , i know frameworks were built by programming languages , and programming languages were built by programming languages :) , my question was why do you think its good , thats all

Comment: Yes, but you ninja-edited your question a few minutes ago :) and it makes more sense to me now.

Comment: its ok , dont worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Because that frameworks provides reusable components that are essential for any high level language implementation: FFI, GC, JIT, linker, debugger and the rest of toolchain. And it's not fun at all to re-implement all that components from scratch.